# CSS Fixed position and media queries

Tags: css, static, position, media-queries, fixed

Im having a problem with media queries and sidebar div with a fixed position. 
Basically when the viewport gets too narrow the main content moves to the left and then sits under the sidebar. I tried to set position to static with the media queries, but then it doesnt work/look the way I want.

Here is the original fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ym7sQ/1/

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    #sidebar {
        position: fixed;
    }
}
```

Here is the one with position static: http://jsfiddle.net/ym7sQ/2/

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    #sidebar {
        position: static;
    }
}
```

You can see that the sidebar is inside the content, but I want it to be overlaying the top and bottom just as it is above 991px. Below 768 its going to stack which is okay because there is not enought space for sidebar and main content. Could you help me with this please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 991px)
#sidebar {
position: fixed;
}
```

I think you should use this.

Comment: position fixed is default value, when you resize you can see that the #main content is showing behind the #sidebar, which is not what I want. I want it to stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

The sidebar overlaps with main content is because the element `.logo` has fixed width(150px) and fixed left/right margin (both 40px), so the the whole width of the `.logo` element is 230px, which is larger than width of `#sidebar` element when the page is narrow enough, so `#sidebar` element is expanded.

**Solution:**
make the `.logo` element width dynamic, like:

> .logo {  width: 80%;  margin: 40px auto 70px; }

Then you may have to use `<img>` tag to show the logo instead of using background.

Comment: I don't think its just the .logo element problem. You should try to resize the window.

Comment: @Jing .logo is not the problem, you can remove the margin and widht,height but still the #main content with images is going to be moved under the sidebar

Comment: @TomChung Exactly, do you have any idea for a fix?

Comment: May be useful see Answers list

Comment: @Richard, try this: keep #sidebar position fixed, Add class "col-xs-3" for the container div of #sidebar, and add "col-xs-9" for the container of #main

Comment: @Jing But I want the content to stack on smaller devices so thats. And when I use col-sm-* then it just shows behind the sidebar. I will just use position: static at lets say below 600px when its all too small but above that I would like it to stay the same.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ym7sQ/16/, changing media query max-width from 991 to 768, is this what you want?

Comment: @Jing I want it stacked at just mobile devices, but at 768px it should still work horizontally. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ym7sQ/17/. The main content can be smaller but I dont know why it gets bigger

Comment: I think that's because the "col-ms-x" class stop working when page width smaller than 768px, you have to use "col-xs-x" instead. However, bootstrap doesn't support smaller divisions under 768px, so you may have to write your own media query to make 480px as a another threshold.

Comment: @Jing Oh okay, then lets say that this is the final one: http://jsfiddle.net/ym7sQ/18/ Now how would I make it just that the sidebar will be stacked on top at max-width: 480px? Currently Im using position: static; but that doesnt work. Thank you

Comment: check this: http://jsfiddle.net/ym7sQ/19/, I override the col-xs-x style in media query for max-width:480px. If you don't want to change col-xs-x style, you can add your own class for #sidebar and #main container div.

Answer (score 0):

check it on http://jsfiddle.net/ym7sQ/14/show

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/ym7sQ/14/

Sorry for change a lot. But the main amendment is move the whole ***#sidebar element*** out of the container.

HTML:

```
<div id="top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">
                 <h2>Home</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="sidebar" class="col-sm-3"><a href="#" class="logo"></a>
    <nav role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <hr />
    <p>info@domain.com
        <br />123 456 789</p>
    <p>Something something</p>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <section id="main">
                    <div id="slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        </ol>
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <img src="http://placekitten.com/1280/720" alt="Slide 1" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="http://placekitten.com/1280/720g" alt="Slide 2" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="http://placekitten.com/1280/720" alt="Slide 3" />
                            </div>
                        </div> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#slider" data-slide="prev">

                            </a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#slider" data-slide="next">

                            </a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="main-bottom">
                        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="Image" /> <a href="contact.html">
                            <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="France" />
                            </a>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">
                <p>2013 &copy; All rights reserved.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but then its stuck on the left side at all times, I would like the website to be centered if possible.

Comment: Thats the same one like before I think.